# Why valueError expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 29907), Confusion about Conv1D regarding fasta sequence classification?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, numpy-ndarray

My data is about genome sequence basically a long string of "AAATTGCCAA...AA". [Here is a pic of my dataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tm4JD.png)

I converted the data into a NumPy array by using the function.

The shape of my data is `(1001,29907)`. In the keras documentation, I found that the input shape is consist of `input_shape=(batchsize, length, channel)`

```
num_classes = 5
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=100, kernel_size=21, strides=1,
    padding="same", input_shape=(29907,1), activation='relu')) 
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=148, strides=1, padding='valid'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

  Model: "sequential_7"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d_7 (Conv1D)            (None, 29907, 100)        2200      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_7 (MaxPooling1 (None, 29760, 100)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_6 (Flatten)          (None, 2976000)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_12 (Dense)             (None, 64)                190464064 
_________________________________________________________________
dense_13 (Dense)             (None, 5)                 325       
=================================================================
Total params: 190,466,589
Trainable params: 190,466,589
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________


batchSize = 16
epoch = 5
model = model.fit(train_data, train_labels,
          batch_size=batchSize,
          epochs=epoch,
          shuffle=True,
          verbose=2,
          validation_data=(valid_data, valid_labels))
```

But when I fit the data into my model it shows a valueError

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_7 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 29907)
```

I didn't get why it acts like this, is my data format is wrong or my input shape is wrong or I define a model in the wrong way.

Here, how is my data look after I convert it into NumPy array is given below

```
array([[1.  , 0.25, 0.25, ..., 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
       [0.75, 0.5 , 0.5 , ..., 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
       [1.  , 0.75, 1.  , ..., 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
       ...,
       [0.5 , 0.25, 0.75, ..., 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
       [0.5 , 0.25, 0.75, ..., 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
       [1.  , 0.75, 1.  , ..., 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: In your dataframe, each row is a one example and you want to predict the corresponding `variant_label` for the `seq` right?

Comment: Yes, the `variant_label` is the corresponding class of the sequence. And I want to predict the sequence that which class it belongs.  @akilat90

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you just need to reshape your `train_data`.

As you mentioned currently the shape of the data is `1001, 29907`. Reshape it to `1001, 29907, 1`.

```
train_data = train_data.reshape(-1, 29907, 1)
```

As `Conv1D` is expecting three dimensions.

---

---

---

**Edit 1** - Based on your comment, you are getting `InvalidArgumentError:  Received a label value of 5 which is outside the valid range of [0, 5)`

You have 5 classes so index the labels from `0-4` instead of `1-5`. To do this, you can run a loop on your labels and subtract 1 from each of the value. So if your array is `[1,1,2,3,5]` it will become `[0,0,1,2,4]`.

Comment: Yes, I also try this, but it shows me `InvalidArgumentError:  Received a label value of 5 which is outside the valid range of [0, 5).`  
In this dataset there are total 5 classes  `df['variant_label'].uique()  = array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])` 
The `train_labels` dataset looks like after I convert it into numpy array - `array([1, 1, 1, ..., 5, 5, 5], dtype=int8)`
and the shape of this is `(1001,)`  Do I need to change shape of the `train_labels` also? 
Plus, my input shape is  `input_shape=(29907,1)`  
Is there any problem with my `input_shape`, the model is given on the question. @coderina

Comment: I have replied to your query in the answer.